# Is the following function rational?

Tags: functions, rational-functions

The rational function is defined as the quotient of two polynomials. Can functions that are equal to rational functions also be called rational, because they have the same properties?

One concrete example I could come up with is:
$$
f(x) = \frac{x+0^{|x|}}{x^2-1} \\
g(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^3-x}
$$

To my understanding these two funtions are identical.
So, is $f$ rational?

Edit: I assume that $0^0$ is undefined as well as $g(0)$ hence $x/x$ is undefined for $x=0$. Also found the error and fixed it.

Comment: It depends.  What, precisely, is your definition of "function"?  What is the value of $0^0$?

Comment: How are you defining $0^0$?  Without including that definition, your function $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$.  If you are defining it to be $1$ then your function is not rational near $x=0$.

Comment: This is the kind of special-case/pedantic thinking that is great to have as we explore mathematics! That being said, my answer would be: in what situation would it ever matter whether the first expression can be called a rational function or not?

Comment: @Greg Martin In a test actually… The task was to define a rational function with $\mathbb{D} = \mathbb{R} \backslash \{-1, 0, 1\}$. I came up with $0^{|x|}$, instead of the second approach. My teacher did not understand the formula and just wrote it off as nonsense. I don’t care about the credits, but I found this question very intriguing.

Comment: *The rational function is defined as the quotient of two polynomials.* --- No, not "the quotient of two polynomials". Rational means being EQUAL (as functions) to the quotient of two polynomials. For example, $f(x) = \frac{e^x(x^2 + 1)}{e^x(x^2 - 4)}$ is a rational function. Also, $g(x) = \frac{(e^x - 1)(x^2 + 1)}{(e^x - 1)(x^2 - 4)}$ is a rational function because it is equal to $h(x) = \frac{x^3 + x}{x^3 - 4x}$ where $h(x)$ is clearly expressible as the quotient of two polynomials (because I wrote a formula for $h(x)$ that is the quotient of two polynomials).